# How to specify category for a product in HTML5 Microdata

Tags: html, microdata

I'm improving the markup for the Products section of a site of mine by using Microdata. Everything is doing just fine, as the info is being showed in the Google results as expected.

But I think it would be nice to specify a category to a given product. I've searched everywhere and rode every attribute spec found in http://Schema.org/Product but it seems there is nothing there I can use to spec a "Category".

I tried to set `itemprop="category"` but Google's Rich Snippet Tool gives me this warn: "Page contains property "category" which is not part of the schema.", which is true.

Does anyone knows which property should I use to designate the Category for a Product? Any thoughts on this would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[schema.org/Offer](http://schema.org/Offer) has [category](http://schema.org/category) property.

> A category for the item. Greater signs or slashes can be used to
>   informally indicate a category hierarchy.

So smth like that will work.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating"
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
   Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>/5
   based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> customer reviews
  </div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">$55.00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
    <span itemprop="category">LargeCategory > SmallCategory</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR

Another option is to use data-vocabulary.org which has *category* property in its Product class. OK for Google, NOT OK for other Search Engines though. But for Google it will work. Smth like that:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="brand">ACME</span> <span itemprop="name">Executive
    Anvil</span>
  <img itemprop="image" src="anvil_executive.jpg" />

  <span itemprop="description">Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the 
    Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler
    looking for something to drop from a height.
  </span>
  Category: <span itemprop="category" content="Hardware > Tools > Anvils">Anvils</span>
  Product #: <span itemprop="identifier" content="mpn:925872">
    925872</span>
  <span itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
    <span itemprop="rating">4.4</span> stars, based on <span itemprop="count">89
      </span> reviews
  </span>

  <span itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
    Regular price: $179.99
    <meta itemprop="currency" content="USD" />
    $<span itemprop="price">119.99</span>
    (Sale ends <time itemprop="priceValidUntil" datetime="2020-11-05">
      5 November!</time>)
    Available from: <span itemprop="seller">Executive Objects</span>
    Condition: <span itemprop="condition" content="used">Previously owned, 
      in excellent condition</span>
    <span itemprop="availability" content="in_stock">In stock! Order now!</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

You can find out more about this vocabulary [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750).

Comment: I like your second approach. It seems more semantic in my case, since my products doesn't have an offer at all. And who cares about the other SE? =p 
Much obliged.

Comment: In price has to be just number, currency has own tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it
On http://schema.org/Product there is category mentioned ( under brand ), still in https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ it apears as an error. 
Have they added this attribute recently?